# MySQL Query multiple tables with data to columns

Tags: mysql, join, select

I need to pull data from three tables and have the result returned in a single row for each user.  I also need to use variable column names based on the value of a field.

My query is:

```
SELECT u.USER_ID, u.FIRST_NAME, d.FIELD_ID, d.DATA, f.LABEL, f.TYPE
    FROM users as u, fields as f, fieldsData as d
    WHERE d.USER_ID=u.USER_ID AND f.FIELD_ID=f.FIELD_ID;
```

The result I get is:

```
|------------|-------------|----------|-----------|---------|----------|
| USER_ID    | FIRST_NAME  | FIELD_ID | DATA      |LABEL    | TYPE     |
|------------|-------------|----------|-----------|---------|----------|
| 1          | John        | 1        | Cookies   | Dessert | TEXT     |
| 1          | John        | 2        | Chocolate | Flavor  | TEXT     |
| 1          | John        | 3        | Milky Way | Candy   | TEXT     |
| 2          | Sally       | 1        | Brownies  | Dessert | TEXT     |
| 2          | Sally       | 3        | Snickers  | Candy   | TEXT     |
|------------|-------------|----------|-----------|---------|----------|
```

What I need is only one row per user with columns for the fields / field data values.  Something like this:

```
|------------|-------------|--------------|----------|---------------|---------------|------------|
| FIRST_NAME | Dessert     | Dessert_TYPE | Flavor   | Flavor_TYPE   | Candy         |Candy_TYPE  |
|------------|-------------|--------------|----------|---------------|---------------|------------|
| John       | Cookies     | TEXT         | Chocolate| TEXT          | Milky Way     | TEXT       |
| Sally      | Brownies    | TEXT         | NULL     | NULL          | Snickers      | TEXT       |
|------------|-------------|--------------|----------|---------------|----------------|------------|
```

Could really use some help on this one!  Thank you!!

USERS TABLE:

```
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| USER_ID    | FIRST_NAME  | LAST_NAME    |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| 1          | John        | Smith        |
| 2          | Sally       | Jones        |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
```

FIELDS TABLE:

```
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| FIELD_ID   | LABEL       | TYPE         |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
| 1          | Dessert     | TEXT         |
| 2          | Flavor      | TEXT         |
| 3          | Candy       | TEXT         |
|------------|-------------|--------------|
```

FIELDS DATA TABLE:

```
|------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
| DATA_ID    | USER_ID     | FIELD_ID     | DATA          |
|------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
| 1          | 1           | 1            | Cookies       |
| 2          | 1           | 2            | Chocolate     |
| 3          | 1           | 3            | Milky Way     |
| 4          | 2           | 1            | Brownies      |
| 5          | 2           | 3            | Snickers      |
|------------|-------------|--------------|---------------|
```

Comment: You might need to add `GROUP BY u.first_name;` at the end;

Comment: How many fields you have ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid They're user defined fields so there could be up to 20.

Answer (score 0):

You must to do a INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT u.USER_ID, u.FIRST_NAME, d.FIELD_ID, d.DATA, f.LABEL, f.TYPE
    FROM fieldsData as d 
    INNER JOIN users as u ON d.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
    INNER JOIN fields as f ON d.FIELD_ID = f.FIELD_ID;
```

I hope It can be useful!

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it results in the same output - multiple rows for the same user and not everything consolidated into a single row.